# When was the Beith Hamiqdash hasheni fully completed?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash

What year was the second Beith Hamiqdash fully completed? Can any one of you answer back with both Hebrew and Secular dates?

Comment: What do you mean by "_fully_ completed" (emphasis added)?

Comment: When the whole construction was done , when you didn't need to build anymore of it

Comment: If you can clarify your question post, please [edit] it to do so. These comments are ephemeral by design and will likely be deleted: your entire question should be in the question post itself. Might I recommend our [tour]?

Comment: RThis question will help me revel the real Achaverosh,because at the Purim story the Beith Hamiqdash wasn't completed, so I will see the king during the time it was completed, and see the king before, and that King will be the one (Achashverosh

Comment: King Herod finished rebuilding the Temple c. 18 BCE. I cannot think of anything more recent.

Comment: No he added new things to the Temple, renovated it, not completed it